# Creating a full vs. reduced model with one explanatory variable

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox

I am attempting to create a Cox proportional hazards model with only one explanatory variable. To perform a likelihood ratio test, I know I need a full and reduced model. I also know that a full model would be a separate mean for each group, and a reduced model would use an overall mean for the whole data set. How can I ensure I am setting this up properly in R? In this model z is 1 if the patient had heart surgery, and z is 0 otherwise

I have:

```
model<-coxph(Surv(time,delta)~z,method='breslow',data=heartdata)

X.lr <- 2*(model$loglik[2]-model$loglik[1])
```

Does this achieve that? I get an answer I just want to know whether this makes a full vs. reduced model since I don't have other variables to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, this does work, but I think there's a better/more transparent solution using `update()` and `anova()` (I wasn't even aware that the log-likelihood component of `coxph` models included both the full and the null deviances).

Using a built-in data set from the `survival` package:

```r
## drop NAs so we are using the same data set for full & reduced models
lungna <- na.omit(lung)
## fit full model
m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lungna)
## update model to fit intercept only (` ~ 1 ` replaces the RHS of the formula):
## ~ 1 means "intercept only" in R formula notation
m0 <- update(m1, . ~ 1)
## anova() runs a likelihood-ratio test
anova(m0,m1)
```

Results:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  Surv(time, status)
 Model 1: ~ 1
 Model 2: ~ ph.ecog
   loglik  Chisq Df P(>|Chi|)    
1 -508.12                        
2 -501.91 12.409  1 0.0004273 ***
```

You can confirm that `2*diff(m1$loglik)` gives 12.409, the same value reported by `anova()` for the deviance ("Chisq") difference, and that `pchisq(chisq_val, df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)` gives the reported p-value.